# how to make a function that allows to change the image when selecting in the dropdown of google translate?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit new to programming and as the title says I wanted to make a function that allowed me to switch between images depending on the text I selected from the google translate dropdown between the id of image1 and image2, allowing me to show an image and hide the another image, but I have no idea how to start.

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'pt',
    autoDisplay: 'true',
    includedLanguages: 'pt,en',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

```html
<script src='//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'></script>
<div class="hero_area">
  <header class="header_section">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom_nav-container ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li style="padding-top: 25px;" class="nav-item">
            <div style="margin-right: 140px;" id='google_translate_element'></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="image1" width="300" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/ti/vetor-gratis/t2/567055-icone-de-pessoa-gr%C3%A1tis-vetor.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="image2" width="300" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1AkIYdHRh_fVi-0j0CdCWCZXeEvOIolZQDSf4l-7oewZSOSReebanjktPa_7JE5LxO84&usqp=CAU" /></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: you could "intercept" the click event, and get the language chosen; please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935450/detect-google-website-translator-change-of-language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Google Website Translator change of language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935450/detect-google-website-translator-change-of-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really much information about the Google Translate button but what I have found that it contains basic select, something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate).
I have created simple [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-tu-mmstde?file=/src/index.js) that illustrates the behavior.

**Explanation:**
First of you need to hide every image but one that reflects initial page language and in your case it is Portugal I think. You can do that by creating a CSS class that sets elements display property to none, something like this:

```
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

and add this class to every  element but one (your initial). And also add id="..." to  element not  one.
Secondly I recommend using something that reflects value from GoogleTranslate select to your images ID's ("option*x*" names are just for presentation purposes, in your case it will be languages that you declare in *includedLanguages* property when initializing Translator ):

```
const optionsToImagesMap = {
  option1: "image1",
  option2: "image2",
  option3: "image3",
  option4: "image4"
};
```

Next up you need to create variable that you will use to manipulate images.

```
let currentImage = document.querySelector("#image1");
```

*currentImage* at the start will contain reference to your initial image that you want to display (the one that reflect Portuguese)

You need to create variable that will have reference to that GoogleTranslate select by doing something like this:

`const googleTranslateSelect = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select")`

Then you need to add event listener to that GoogleTranslate select do something when language changes:

```
googleTranslateSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    //do something
  });
```

In that eventListener you will hide one image and display other by adding class *none* from one image, swapping reference to new image and then removing that class from the new *currentImage*:

```
googleTranslateSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    //do something
    currentImage.classList.add("none");
    currentImage = document.querySelector(
      `#${optionsToImagesMap[e.target.value]}`
    );
    currentImage.classList.remove("none");
  });
```

Comment: only there is a problem. how can i add a value to each select option in google_translate_element?

Comment: The value is already there. I think it corresponds to shortcuts of languages eg. Portuguese = pt. You initialize your button with "pt,en" so I guess you found somewhere what values correspond to English and Portuguese. If not i suggest finding some documentation about this button or use link to w3schools that I provided.